# Assignments in the condition part of if and while statements

Tags: javascript, jslint

Here is quote by [Crockford](http://crockford.com/javascript/code.html):

> ## Assignment Expressions
>
> Avoid doing assignments in the condition part of if and while statements.
>
> Is
>
> ```
> if (a = b) {
> ```
>
> a correct statement? Or was
>
> ```
> if (a == b) {
> ```
>
> intended? Avoid constructs that cannot easily be determined to be correct.

```
// Here is an assignment as I understand it:
var var1 = "foo";
var var2 = "bar";

// And what is shown in Crockford's quote isn't an assignment.
```

So, what does Crockford's quote mean?

Comment: @nurdyguy: Not always. Try this: `var b = ""; var a; if (a = b) { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that

```
if (a = b) {
```

is actually an assignment, assigning the value of `b` to `a`, which is not usually what one wants.

That passage is just telling you to watch out that you do that only when you really mean it, which you usually don't. Usually one wants to do a comparison there, so

```
if (a == b) {
```

Counterexample: if you run the following, it will print `true` only if you give OK to the confirm popup, nothing otherwise.

```js
if(a = confirm('test')) { console.log(a) }
```

Notice that there's an assignment and we're printing the value of `a` inside the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   var username = prompt("username");
   var password = prompt("password");

   if(username = "youdontknowme") 
     if(password = "12345678")
        alert("logged in successfully!");
```

Seems right? Just try it! Therefore most IDEs will warn you that the assignment might should be a comparison instead. And if you dont have such a vlever IDE, you need to spot it yourself, thats why Mr. Crockford tries to make you aware of it.